# How do I check for invalid credentials while making a ssl connection in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, authorization, snmp

I have this method which tries to catch an exception that might be thrown when supplied with invalid credentials when connecting through SSL. The credentials are supplied through SNMP. But I am not always able to interpret the exception as invalid credentials, as you can see I am only trying to read the message of exception thrown which differs from a device to device.

Is what am I doing correct? Are there any foolproof ways to check if the credentials needed to make the connection is valid? I am totally lost here as the exception message thrown changes from device to device.

Thanks for any pointers.

```
try
{
    string ipSSL = string.Format(URL_CWIS_HELPSTRING, "s", SecurityBindingProxy.Destination.Address.Value.Host, "/");
    System.Net.WebRequest https = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(ipSSL);
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = WsdlClient.ServiceRequirements.WsdlServiceRequirements.SSLCheckCallback;
    https.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(SNMP.ConnectionInfo.Instance.Username, SNMP.ConnectionInfo.Instance.Password); ;
    System.Net.HttpWebResponse responseSSL = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)https.GetResponse();
    responseSSL.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex.Message.Contains("Unauthorized")
        || ex.Message.Contains("401"))
    {
        return -2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you not catching an exception type instead of checking if the message contains "Unauthorized"?

Comment: @Ramhound: because, i don't know which specific type of exception to be catch. Also these exception contains error messages which sometimes say http 401, sometimes 404 and no proper .net exception class. This is my exact problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to be catching a more specific type of exception rather than parsing  exception messages. If you look at the docs for [GetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx) you'll see documented the types of exceptions thrown. If you catch a `WebException` then this will allow you to find out the HTTP status without parsing strings manually e.g.:

```
catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
{
    var errorResponse = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
    if (errorResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to know how to catch invalid credentials related exceptions.

Comment: Would not an response code that indicates the user is not authorized to view the content indicate there was a problem with the credentials?

Comment: @Duncan Smart: Wow! Thanks a lot for teaching something new, I can make my code more elegant now. But, I am trying to make a connection to number of devices through SNMP and all these devices seems to throw a variety of HttpWebResponse for invalid credentials. I just now tried your suggestion but it didn't helped much.

Comment: I think it's up to you to do some investigation and log the StatusCodes you do get from these devices.

Comment: @DuncanSmart: Till now I was doing that only. I was just thinking if some other elegant approach was available. I will accept your solution as I learned something new. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes unfortunately it seems everyone doesn't follow the HTTP spec to the letter!